# Send data with $.ajax GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, parameters, get

I need to send data with a get request, but I don't want to append the parameters to the string, I'd like to send a data object.

According to the jQuery documentation, it's supposed to work, the object being parsed to a string before the request being sent.

Yet it doesn't work.

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(_this).data('action-service-collect-point'),
    data : {
        lat: position.coords.lat,
        lng: position.coords.lng
        },
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(res){
        ...
        },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
        ...
        }
    });
```

It only calls the url without any parameter.

Comment: Are `position.coords.lat` and `position.coords.lng` defined?

Comment: Also, are you sure the url is what you think it is? The code looks fine assuming the unknowns are correct. One other thing, is url a local resource or remote?

Comment: @BillCriswell   the url is a local one. And yes, lat and lng are defined.

Comment: What happens if you unset `dataType`? Are you sure the server is sending the right response headers?

Comment: @BillCriswell It is still calling the url with no parameters.

Comment: Then I don't see what is wrong. Are you sure the URL the request is sent to does not contain `?lat=...&lon=...`? How did you verify that it doesn't? Did you check the network tab? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: @BillCriswell Yes I'm checking the network tab. it's calling `qr-example-return-geolocate.json` instead of `qr-example-return-geolocate.json?lat=...&lng=...`

Comment: I did this quick test: http://jsfiddle.net/GKUFf/ and it definitely works. Make sure you check your network tab.

Comment: Oh well it works now. Apparently didn't like the fact that my lng and lat object attributes were not between quotes ?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. Glad it's fixed, though!

Answer (score -2):

```
 function showLocation(location) {

      $.ajax({  
          url: "yourfile",
          data: {
            'lat': location.coords.latitude,
            'lng': location.coords.longitude,
            'alt': location.coords.altitudeAccuracy,
            'date':Date()
          },
          type: 'POST'

      });

     }
```

Insert you ajax in a function that its run when load de page for example

Comment: OP Question was sending data with `GET` http method, not `POST`. Please change answer accordingly, if possible.